# What is the change of Laplacian operator under small coordinate transformation?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, laplacian, perturbation-theory

Consider the Laplacian operator $\nabla^{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\frac{\partial}{\partial q^{i}}\left(\sqrt{g}g^{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial q^{j}}\right)$.

How does the Laplacian operator transform under an infinitesimal change $x^{i}(x)=x^{i}+\varepsilon\xi^{i}(x)$?

I know how to work out the transformation rules for the metric and the derivatives, but I don't undertand how $\sqrt{g}$ should transform.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I know how the metric and the derivatives changes and I tried to plug everything together, but I'm struggling with all the expansions.

Comment: It is certainly a very involved calculation. Are you clear on how $\sqrt{g}$ transforms? Are you neglecting terms of order $\epsilon^2$?

Comment: No, I'm not certain how it transforms, and keeping things to first order is a pain so far.

Comment: You aren't certain about $\sqrt{g}$?

Comment: Sorry. It's edited now.

Comment: The best way to get your question unlocked would be to provide your own efforts and some context for the question. You can do this by editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol $g$ without indices refers to the determinant of the matrix of components of the metric tensor $g_{ij}$. Lets refer to this matrix as $\mathbb{G}=[g_{ij}]$.

Now lets see how $g=\mathrm{det} \mathbb{G}$ transforms when $g_{ij} \rightarrow g_{ij}+\delta g_{ij}.$

$$ \mathrm{det}\mathbb{G} \rightarrow \mathrm{det}(\mathbb{G} + \delta \mathbb{G})  $$

$$=\mathrm{det}\Big(\mathbb{G}( \mathbb{I}+ \mathbb{G}^{-1}\delta \mathbb{G})\Big)  $$
$$=\mathrm{det}\Big(\mathbb{G}\Big) \mathrm{det}\Big( \mathbb{I}+ \mathbb{G}^{-1}\delta \mathbb{G})\Big)  $$
$$=\mathrm{det}\Big(\mathbb{G}\Big) \mathrm{det}\Big( \mathbb{I}+ \mathbb{G}^{-1}\delta \mathbb{G})\Big)  $$

Now note that $\det(\mathbb{I}+\epsilon A) \approx 1 + \epsilon Tr(A)$

$$=\mathrm{det}\Big(\mathbb{G}\Big) \Big( 1+ Tr(\mathbb{G}^{-1}\delta \mathbb{G})\Big)  $$

$$=\mathrm{det}(\mathbb{G})+ \mathrm{det}(\mathbb{G}) \sum_{i,k} \mathbb{G}^{-1}_{ik} \delta \mathbb{G}_{ki} $$

$$=g+ g \ g^{\mu\nu} \delta g_{\mu\nu} $$

So we have,

$$g \rightarrow g+ g \ g^{\mu\nu} \delta g_{\mu\nu}, $$

or

$$\delta g = g \ g^{\mu\nu} \delta g_{\mu\nu},$$

from this it is easy to use derivatives to show that,

$$ \sqrt{g} \rightarrow \sqrt{g+\delta g} $$

$$ = \sqrt{g(1 +\delta g/g)} $$

$$ = \sqrt{g}\sqrt{1 +\delta g/g} $$

$$ = \sqrt{g}\Big(1 +\frac12 \frac{\delta g}{g}\Big) $$

$$ = \sqrt{g} +\frac12 \frac{\delta g}{\sqrt{g}} $$

$$ = \sqrt{g} +\frac12  \frac{ g\ g^{\mu\nu} \delta g_{\mu\nu}}{\sqrt{g}} $$

$$ = \sqrt{g} +\frac12 \sqrt{g} \  g^{\mu\nu} \delta g_{\mu\nu} $$

so we have,

$$ \sqrt{g} \rightarrow \sqrt{g} +\frac12 \sqrt{g} \  g^{\mu\nu} \delta g_{\mu\nu} $$

Comment: This is the extent to which I am willing to work the problem You indicated in the comments that you don't know how $\sqrt{g}$ transforms so I have worked it out here. For the rest you are either on your own, or you will need someone willing to slog through the rest of the calculation.

Comment: Thanks, how do you get the identity $\det(\mathbb{I}+\epsilon A) \approx 1 + \epsilon Tr(A)$?

Comment: It is a well known identity. You can see my derivation of it here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1174639/series-expansion-of-the-determinant-for-a-matrix-near-the-identity .

Comment: You can also search something like "derivative of determinant near identity". I think Terrance Tao has an article with a derivation.

Comment: This is the Terrance Tao article I was thinking of. The identity is in equation (4). He doesn't derive it, but this might give you some search terms for further investigation. https://www.google.com/amp/s/terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/matrix-identities-as-derivatives-of-determinant-identities/amp/

Comment: Got it. Knowing how the determinant changes I think I can compute the rest on my own. It will be an awful expression, but straightforward enough it seems.

Comment: If you don't mind I would like to edit your question to specify that the missing piece you needed to solve the problem was the transformation for $g$. If you believe that my contribution helped you to solve the problem, then it would be appropriate to accept my answer.

Comment: Just want to say that you were quite correct http://www.roma1.infn.it/teongrav/VALERIA/TEACHING/ONDE_GRAV_STELLE_BUCHINERI/AA2006_2007/DISPENSE/variational_principle.pdf